# Sprite-based menu doesn't seem to work within a position:fixed div

Tags: css, sprite

I've found allot of helpful things on this site for making a fixed position menu and for doing a sprite based rollover menu. Now, I'm trying to combine the two and it doesn't seem to work.  Within the fixed position div, the background image used for the menu items doesn't move or allow me to change position either through code or on hover.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post some code so we can see whats going on

Comment: Can you post your code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
The Css:
.Interact a {width: 143px; height: 24px; display: block; border: solid 0px #000;background: url(#IMG#);background-repeat:no-repeat;position:relative;background-attachment:scroll;}
.Q a:link, .Q a:visited{background-position:0 0;}
.Q a:hover {background-position: 0 -24;}

.floating-menu {position:fixed;top:-10;background:#FFF;border:1px solid #000;width:100px;z-index:11;}
.floating-menu a, div.floating-menu h3 {display:block;margin:0;}


The HTML:
<div class="floating-menu">
<h4>Menu</H4>
<div class="Interact Q"><a href="#"><img s rc="#BLANKIMG#" width=143 height=24></a></div>
</div>
```